# Scapy on Windows - OS Error?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, scapy, raw-sockets

I run scapy on windows with python 2.6.3.

I tried to run a code i found but a get an OSError [Errno 9] every time.

I didn't find any syntex mistake.

What am i doing wrong?

This is the source code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import socket
host = raw_input('Host: ')
target = socket.gethostbyname(host)
src = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print "Target IP: ",target
print "Source IP: ",src

srcPort = RandShort()
icmpCodes = [1,2,3,9,10,13]
#startPort = 1
#maxPort = 1024
ports = [21,22,23,25,53,80,110,111,123,143,161,194,443,465,993]
print 'scan is starting...'
for port in ports:
    ans = sr1(IP(dst=target)/TCP(sport=srcPort,dport=port,flags="S"))
    if(str(type(ans))=="<type 'NoneType'>"):
        print "Port %s: Filtered" %(port)
    elif(ans.haslayer(TCP)):
        if(ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x012):#(SYN,ACK)
            send_rst = sr(IP(dst=target)/TCP(sport=srcPort,dport=port,flags="R"))
            print "Port %s: Open" %(port)
        elif (ans.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x014):#(RST)
            print "Port %s: Closed" %(port)
    elif(ans.haslayer(ICMP)):
        if(int(ans.getlayer(ICMP).type)==3 and int(ans.getlayer(ICMP).code) in     icmpCodes): #Destination Unreachable  
            print "Port %s: Filtered" %(port)
```

And this is the error i get:

```
Host: www.google.com
Target IP:  173.194.66.147
Source IP:  192.168.1.8
scan is starting...
Begin emission:
Finished to send 1 packets.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Document\Desktop\my_project\TcpSynPortScan_scapy.py", line 16, in <module>
ans = sr1(IP(dst=target)/TCP(sport=srcPort,dport=port,flags="S"))
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 335, in sr1
a,b=sndrcv(s,x,*args,**kargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 431, in sndrcv
os.write(1, ".")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
>>>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on Linux, it seems to be good.

Actually it try to use the bad pipe, try to debug with Logger or Process Monitor !